# Is there a predict hidden feature when select in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @webPortalId int = 7
DECLARE @defaultVidyoPortalId int

SELECT TOP 1 
    @defaultVidyoPortalId = ISNULL(psv.value, 0)
FROM 
    portalsetting ps
INNER JOIN 
    portalsettingvalue psv ON psv.portalsettingid = ps.id 
                           AND psv.portalid = @webPortalId
WHERE 
    ps.name = 'default_portal_id'
ORDER BY
    psv.id DESC
```

I got an exception

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'my-portal' to data type int

The thing that does not make sense to me is: actually, the select statement should never return any result, because no row will return, but why SQL Server tries to convert varchar to int, even the select does not return any data?

`my-portal` is the first row value in table `portalsettingvalue`, but if I only run the `select *` that statement will return nothing.

`portalsettingvalue.value` column is nullable `varchar(1024)`

PS: This happens only on one environment, other environments do not have this issue.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think 'my-portal' is a value (e.g. data in the table) according to the error message.

Comment: @Xin What is the data type of psv.portalId? And also of psv.value ?

Comment: Ive seen this when data in the table itself is the problem. Generally see this in our development environment when devs leave test data behind that doesn’t match the context of what should be inside the table. Suppose this could be eliminated had we better constraints, but it’s the truth.

Comment: Hi @Dijkgraaf I've updated the question to cover your questions. Thank you

Comment: Because you are trying to assign it to a variable you defined as an int, it is trying to cast your varchar as an integer and failing.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf `select @defaultVidyoPortalId = ISNULL('1234',0)` will still work, as it implicit convert the string to int. But the weird thing is: the query will return nothing, so I am confused why SQL Server tries to convert a value which will not be the query result.